# Paypal wants me to manually accept payment made through Ubercart?

Tags: drupal, paypal, ubercart

I have a PayPal Premier account, setup with IPN and with Ubercart's IPN return URL (since you can't leave it blank anymore)

I'm using the "PayPal Website Payments Standard" in Ubercart. "Complete Sale" is selected so that it captures/authorizes the funds on payment submission.

It appears that everything is running fine, however, I have found users not getting their digital product immediately as promised, and the transaction in my PayPal account is waiting for "action" (Accept or Deny)

Did I miss a setting in PayPal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that because the currency I received in my PayPal account wasn't added (I only had USD, received GBP), their "Block payments" rules fired by default and required me to accept or deny payment. I've set it to not block payments, accept and convert them automatically, as well as add GBP to one of the currencies I accept. It appears to be working.

Comment: Unregistered PayPal buyers will still need to click a 'Return to merchant' button before being redirected back to your website automatically, just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's a limitation of Website Payments Standard, which requires unregistered PayPal buyers to click a 'Return to merchant' button before they're directed back to your website.
Try and see if you can set up Express Checkout within Ubercart, as this doesn't have this limitation (Express Checkout is completely free, as well).